# Month & Company view

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table that has a bunch of companies listed in it. I need to make a dictionary view that combines some of the company data, and in addition, every month of the past 3 years up to the current month. 
So for example I would pull the cmp_num, then have additional columns for year and month. It's important that the actual years not be hard coded, since I would want this to continue to work in the following years.

```
cmp1, 2014, 11
cmp1, 2014, 10
cmp1, 2014, 09 
...etc for all months of 2014
cmp1, 2013, 01 
...etc for all months of 2013
cmp1, 2014
...etc for all  months of 2012
*and so on for all companies
```

Do I need a seed table with the years and months listed? Or is there a way to create this on the fly with a calculating view? Which approach would be better in tsql? 
Here's a List of the stuff I need to join with the year\month list.

```
[cmp_code]
[Name]
[City]
[State]
[GroupNo]
[lastname]
```

Comment: You can do either way. Depends on your preferences. You can generate the list on the fly using recursive CTE. I'd try that first and see if the performance is OK. If not you can create a dedicated table, which of course needs to be maintained.

Comment: Do you know how to craft that cte? I need help with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said, you can do both. Here is a CTE you can use to generate the list for 3 years back. If the performance is not good enough, you should consider creating dedicated table.

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT 1 AS id, DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE()) AS [year], DATEPART(MONTH,GETDATE()) AS [month]

  UNION ALL

  SELECT 
    id + 1 AS id, 
    CASE WHEN [month] = 1 THEN [year]-1 ELSE [year] END AS [year],
    CASE WHEN [month] = 1 THEN 12 ELSE [month] - 1 END AS [month]
  FROM cte WHERE id < 36
)
SELECT [Name], [year], [month] 
FROM cte CROSS JOIN dbo.viewFranchiseList
```

Comment: OK. Now how would I go about joining that to a table that has company data in this query?

Comment: I added the additional info my OP was missing. Those are the values from another view I need to add the year&month data to.

Comment: I'm confused. Are you asking about how to join it to the table of companies? is that your question?

Comment: Yes. I find the syntax confusing. Do I just put some arbitrary ON statement in there to grab everything? ex: FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.viewFranchiseList ON year >= year

Comment: You need to use CROSS JOIN, this will give you all possible combinations of company vs month/year, I updated the answer.